# How to re-install MDAC on SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, mdac

I am having problems when connecting to my SQL server 2008 and think it might be a problem related to MDAC. Is there a download to re-install these?

Answer (score 2):

[MDAC 2.8 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=78cac895-efc2-4f8e-a9e0-3a1afbd5922e&DisplayLang=en)

Remember, MDAC is client software that should not be installed on the server.

Your problem is more likely a protocol or firewall error.
Can you give more info please?

Comment: Microsoft: Overview:
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.8 SP1 contains core Data Access components such as the Microsoft SQL Server™ OLE DB provider and ODBC driver. This redistributable installer for the MDAC 2.8 SP1 release installs the same Data Access components as Microsoft Windows XP SP2.

XP SP2 is really outdated isn' it? The Question goes about SQL Server 2008 but i don't know which version of OS - i guess win2008.
What is the correct MDAC Version for this kind of OS (64-bit)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with gbn; check that you are allowing remote connections on the SQL server, it is disabled by default in some versions; use the Configuration Manager on the server to verify TCP/IP is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The MDAC is an ODBC driver for client access. But you need it for ASP and ASP.Net database connections.

The MDAC 2.8 SP1 does not install in Windows 2008 Server because it was designed for a older version of Windows.

You might be able to enable access, I think that under IIS 6.0 32 bit drivers and programs are disabled by default. See this Microsoft Forum post for more info:
http://forums.iis.net/p/1146917/1882658.aspx#1882658

You need to check your Application Pool settings for IIS and see if the enable 32 bit applications is set to true, if it is set to false change it to true and then restart the IIS service. The MDAC and ODBC drivers are 32 bit and you need to enable 32 bit app access in the application pools as in the 64 bit Windows 20008 Server RC1/RC2 versions it is set to false by default.

See if that solves your problem.

I tried even installing MS-Office, but still no database access. Not until I enabled 32 bit access in the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MDAC checker first, it will tell you if there's a problem with your MDAC:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307255

Comment: Are you sure: Article ID: 307255 - Last Review: March 27, 2007 - Revision: 12.2
Is there anything newer, for some recent os-versions like win2008?

Comment: unless windows 2008/2008 R2 come with something newer than MDAC 2.8 SP1 then I'd expect it to work. It's not entirly clear from the FAQ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692877(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, they renamed MDAC to WDAC in Server 2008 which really throws your search strings off. To fix WDAC you need to run system file checker "sfc /scannow"